# Blurry text Electron

Tags: electron, text-rendering

I have has some issues with text and icon fonts looking blurry in an electron application. I have tested the same HTML page in Chrome and the text and icon font look much crisper.

[image: Chrome and Electron]

After zooming the image I can see that Chrome is using subpixel rendering but Electron is only rendering in grayscale. I have tried using `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` but it does not seem to change anything.

[image: Subpixel rendering]

Chrome Browser version: 53.0.2785.116
Electron version (process.versions.electron): 1.4.1
Electron Chrome version (process.versions.chrome): 53.0.2785.113

What causes this and how should I fix it?

Comment: which version of electron are you using?

Comment: More specifically, what chromium version is this?

Comment: Are you using translate3d on the offending elements?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli No, all I am doing is setting the font and size.

Comment: Have you tried setting `-webkit-font-smoothing` to `aliased` to see if it makes any difference? Or even setting it to `none`? That would be a possible way to see if it affects anything at all.

Comment: Same Issue, Electron 4.1

Comment: Hmm... Actually for me even the text gets blurry a little. I am not sure if thats because of the theme I am using. I am using light vs theme

Answer (score 2):

Try to set:

```
backgroundColor: '#FFF'
```

in the BrowserWindow constructor options.

[The corresponding issue on Electron's tracker](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10025)

Comment: It is also now in the [FAQ](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-font-looks-blurry-what-is-this-and-what-can-i-do)